# Pandas DataFrame --> GroupBy --> MultiIndex Process

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, hierarchical-data, multi-index

I'm trying to restructure a large DataFrame of the following form as a MultiIndex:

```
        date  store_nbr  item_nbr  units  snowfall  preciptotal  event
0 2012-01-01          1         1      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
1 2012-01-01          1         2      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
2 2012-01-01          1         3      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
3 2012-01-01          1         4      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
4 2012-01-01          1         5      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
```

I want to group by `store_nbr` (1-45), within each `store_nbr` group by `item_nbr` (1-111) and then for the corresponding index pair (e.g., `store_nbr`=12, `item_nbr`=109), display the rows in chronological order, so that ordered rows will look like, for example:

```
store_nbr=12, item_nbr=109:   date=2014-02-06, units=0, snowfall=...
                              date=2014-02-07, units=0, snowfall=...
                              date=2014-02-08, units=0, snowfall=...
...                           ...
store_nbr=12, item_nbr=110:   date=2014-02-06, units=0, snowfall=...
                              date=2014-02-07, units=1, snowfall=...
                              date=2014-02-08, units=1, snowfall=...
...
```

It looks like some combination of `groupby` and `set_index` might be useful here, but I'm getting stuck after the following line:

```
grouped = stores.set_index(['store_nbr', 'item_nbr'])
```

This produces the following MultiIndex:

```
                         date  units  snowfall  preciptotal  event
store_nbr item_nbr                                                
1         1        2012-01-01      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
          2        2012-01-01      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
          3        2012-01-01      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
          4        2012-01-01      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
          5        2012-01-01      0       0.0          0.0    0.0
```

Does anyone have any suggestions from here? Is there an easy way to do this by manipulating groupby objects?

Comment: Please include outputs as text and not images.

Comment: Sorry! Updated.

Comment: you can sort your rows with df.sort_values(by='date')

Comment: Thanks @SandervandenOord -- if you want to post as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your rows with:

```
df.sort_values(by='date')
```